# Python in javascript (Brython) execute function with timeout

Tags: python, multithreading, timeout, brython

I'm trying to execute a python function with a timeout, I've found some good ideas on stackoverflow but they don't seem to work for me as I'm executing the python function from javascript (using Brython) and multithreading/sleep don't work well (no sleep function in javascript). Any idea relatively easy to implement that would allow me to terminate a function if its execution takes more than 10s (see logic below):

```
def function_to_execute:
    print("function executing")

time_out=10
exec(function_to_execute)
time_function_started=time()
if time()>(time_function_startedtime_out) and function_to_execute not complete: (simplified for clarity)
    function_to_execute.terminate()
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I know is by using 2 thread worker and kill it. one worker for running the function, another one for maintain the running time.

I think you can use `python-worker` ([link](https://pypi.org/project/python-worker/))

```
import time
from worker import worker

@worker
def run_with_limit(worker_object, timeout):
    time.sleep(timeout)
    worker_object.abort()

@worker
def my_controlled_function(a, b, c):
   ...

## then you can run it

run_with_limit(my_controlled_function(1, 2, 3), timeout=10)
```

if you dont want to use `time.sleep` you have an alternative like this

```
@worker
def run_with_limit(worker_object, timeout):
    while 1:
        if worker_object.work_time >= 10:
            worker_object.abort()
            break
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately I don't seem to be able to use workers with Brython